# PropertyUtils failed to convert boolean if the getter uses "is" rather than "get"

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to use PropertyUtils class's copyProperties method to copy a bean.

The problem is that it fails to copy boolean if the getter of the boolean is written as "isXXX". It only works if the getter of the boolean is "getXXX". For example,

```
class MyBean {
....
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
....
}
```

PropertyUtils.copyProperties does not work for this class. But it works for this:

```
class MyBean {
....
    public boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
....
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: Is the type of `enable` property `Boolean` or `boolean`?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the `enabled` type:

If it is `boolean`, then the getter must be in this form:

```
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
```

If it `Boolean`, then the getter must be in this form:

```
// The return type of the function doesn't matter Boolean or boolean
public Boolean getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
```